# Ajax call after jQuery UI Confirmation Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am working on a module for users to verify their mobile numbers using the 3 usual steps:

Enter mobile number -> Receive pin -> Enter pin for verification

My form contains:

- 2 Textboxes:

  - Mobile Number (Visible on page load)
  - Pin (Replaces "Mobile #" after AJAX response)
- 1 "Next" Button

My code looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-product">
  <div id="dob_form">
    <label for="input-phone-number">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" id="input-phone-number" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="button-next" />
</form>
```

**JS**

*(the actual code contains additional condition checking that don't serve a purpose here so I stripped it down for clarity)*

```
$('#button-next').bind('click', function() {

$.ajax({
    url: (api url),
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#dob_form :input'),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,

    success: function(json) {

        if (json['phone-step'] == 1 && json['valid-number']) { //api returns that it's the phone number step and the number is valid

            $('#dob_form').html('' +
            '<label for="input-pin">Pin Code</label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="pin_code" value="" id="input-pin"  />');      

       } else if (json['pin-step'] == 1 && json['valid-pin']) { //api returns that it's the pin validation step and the pin is valid

          window.location.href = json['redirect'];

       } else { //show error }

   }
});

});
```

This is all working fine.

However, what I want to add is a modal **confirmation dialog** that appears **only before sending the "PIN" AJAX call**.

In other words, clicking "NEXT" the first time sends the call directly, but in the second step, when the user enters the pin and clicks "NEXT", I want to display a confirmation dialog. 
If he/she clicks "OK" the AJAX call would be sent; on "Cancel" it simply closes the dialog box and wouldn't send the call.

I managed to do that using an **if statement** and a **confirm() dialog**; however, I want to add a customized dialog using **jQuery UI**.

I couldn't figure out how to do that because I couldn't find a way to get a response from the jQuery UI dialog.

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Any dialog built using jQuery UI won't be synchronous, so you can't get a return value in the same way. You would need to use event handlers.

Comment: How would I tackle it in my case then?

Comment: @el3ati2, would you be able to provide a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm not sure how to replicate the ajax call to the php api in jsfiddle :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to craft a working example, and learned a bit of jQuery UI along the way!

I had to extract your event handler and data-sending functionality into separate functions to improve readability. Basically, I check whether `#input-pin` exists in the HTML every time your `#button-next` is clicked, and use that to determine whether the phone number has already been sent. If it hasn't, I show a dialog. Otherwise, I send the data, which is presumably a phone number.

To make the example below work, I had to add a little checkbox that allows you to pretend as if you got a valid response after sending a phone number. You can remove those lines in both the HTML and the JS without breaking the rest of the functionality.

```js
$('#button-next').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#input-pin').length) {
        $('#confirm-send-pin').dialog({
            height: "auto",
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Send PIN': function () {
                    sendData()
                    $(this).dialog('close')
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close')
                }
            }
        })
    } else sendData()
})

function sendData() {
    console.log('Data sent!')
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.example.com/api-path',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#dob_form :input'),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: onDataReceived
    })
}
      
      
function onDataReceived (json) {
    if (json['phone-step'] == 1 && json['valid-number']) {
        $('#dob_form').html('' +
            '<label for="input-pin">Pin Code</label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="pin_code" value="" id="input-pin" />')
    } else if (json['pin-step'] == 1 && json['valid-pin']) {
        window.location.href = json['redirect'];
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
}

// This is just to make the example work

$('#test-dialog').on('change', function () {
    onDataReceived({ 'phone-step': 1, 'valid-number': 1 })
    this.disabled = true
})
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-product">
  <div id="dob_form">
    <label for="input-phone-number">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" id="input-phone-number" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="button-next" />
</form>
<div id="confirm-send-pin" title="Send PIN?" style="display:none">
  <p>Are you sure you want to send this PIN?</p>
</div>


<!-- Makes the example work -->
<label for="test-dialog">Pretend you sent a phone number</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="test-dialog" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I based my code on your answer with a few modifications and I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the jQuery UI dialog box to return a `Deferred` object, which will tell you whether the OK or Cancel action was chosen:

```
function confirmDialog() {
    my def = $.Deferred();
    $('#myDiv').dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: [ {
           'ok': def.resolve,
           'cancel': def.reject
       } ]
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

and then combine this using `.then` Promise chaining to only send the AJAX call if the `confirmDialog` is "resolved":

```
confirmDialog().then(sendAJAX);
```